# Typescript Generics : what is wrong here?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

i can't compile this kind of thing:

```
type F<A> = (a:A)=>A;

class CLAZZ<S extends { [k: string]: any }, K extends keyof S = keyof S>{
  constructor(a:S){
    this._o=a;
  }
  _o:S;
  set(k:K, f:F<S[K]>){
     f(this._o[k]);
  }
}

type O = {
  pippo: number,
  pluto: string | null,
  paperino: {[k:string]:boolean}
}

let o = new CLAZZ<O>({"paperino":{}, pluto:null, pippo:1});

o.set("paperino", (paperino)=>({...paperino, "ciccio":true}))
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgPAQQHxQLxQBQEMBcCCUqSCA3AFBkDGANlgM51QDCAMggFrtwDKUEAHsAgA7ACaMA3lADaAaxxQ6wAE4BLYQHMAugqzCQUAL4AaKAGk%20gkeKiyIIAPYAzKL3R3HL7kglkoUSgdhJWUAV0pgB2VsHG58X39-YAALVToAOgB9B1Qscn9DPyhs2PzFCGAMeTNTJxx4bmkzLSR4osSnDBS0rIc5LXwywsKyUEgoAHk0KASoMFUwMAcFYVCAWwAjCGVjIrBqUMiFEPUNKAAfKFXqal3-MCxINWFlmbkcE80dDYcHagg9MMKP9gFAHNNhBAAO7MNicOATJAYCQAIgeT3UDhROAkJjmByO11ucwWSxwAEZDIMKA50nQKhg0Y9tpiUaYMOiWS9CEiJOl%20Zzng5TCjKKpKGKsTgVKEIFT8GQgA)

the last line give this error:

> Spread types may only be created from object types.

this because the paperino argument is inferred as

> (parameter) paperino: string | number | {
> [k: string]: boolean; } | null

and not just as

> { [k: string]: boolean; }

as i'm expecting...

also forcing the parameter type give me an error

> o.set("paperino", (paperino:  {[k:string]:boolean})=>({...paperino,"ciccio":true}))

> Argument of type '(paperino: { [k: string]: boolean;
> }) => { ciccio: true; }' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'F<string | number | { [k: string]: boolean; } | null>'.   Types of
> parameters 'paperino' and 'a' are incompatible.
> Type 'string | number | { [k: string]: boolean; } | null' is not assignable to type '{ [k: string]: boolean; }'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type '{ [k: string]: boolean; }'.

any solution other than... "any"?

Comment: Because TS figures out types when you create an object, not when you call `set`, if you want types to be narrowed when you call a function, you can make it generic as well, something like `set<K1 extends K>(k:K1, f:F<S[K1]>)` should do. (`CLAZZ<O>` that just looks a bit misspelled :D )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just move the key generic to the `set` method: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgPAQQHxQLxQBQEMBcCCUqSCA3AFBkDGANlgM51QDCAMggFrtwDKUEAHsAgA7ACaMA3lADaAaxxQ6wAE4BLYQHMAugqzCQUAL5IJZKFEoB7YUuUBXSsEvLsObvlPnzwABaq6AHQA%20paoWOTmhmZQIW4RihDAcADSfIIi4lCyECCWAGZQ3EgY8skANFB5OPDc0slaSB7RXnkYvv7BlnJa%20PFRUWSgkFAA8mhQnlBgqmBglgrCdgC2AEYQymXRYNR2Tgq26hpQAD5Qi9TUm%20ZgWJBqwvMTcjgHmjorlpbUEHr9FN-AKCWcbCCAAd2YbE4cBGxQkACIbnd1JZ4TgJIYKttdvNzpcpjM5jgAIyGXoUSwBOiJDCI27rFHwioYJEMh6EOEBLms%206WCrwyiqSiC1E4FR2CBk-BkIA)